# Functoriality of the local Artin reciprocity

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $k$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Then the local Artin reciprocity tells us that
$$\text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)^{\text{ab}}\cong \hat{k^\times}.$$
If we have a finite extension $\bar{k}/l/k$, then we have a natural inclusion $\text{Gal}(\bar{k}/l)^{\text{ab}}\to \text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)^{\text{ab}}$. I would like to understand the corresponding map $\hat{l^\times}\to \hat{k^\times}$. For any extension $l'/l$ the map
$$\text{Gal}(l'/l)\cong l^\times/N_{l'/l}(l'^\times)\longrightarrow \text{Gal}(l'/k)\cong k^\times/N_{l'/k}(l'^\times)$$
is induced by the norm $N_{l/k}$. It would seem natural that the continuous map $\hat{l^\times}\to \hat{k^\times}$ is given by the completion of the norm $l^\times \to k^\times$. But that doesn't make sense, no? Because this map isn't injective, and the inclusion is. Clearly I'm missing something stupid...

Comment: Usually there is no inclusion $\text{Gal}(\bar{l}/l)^{\text{ab}}\to \text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)^{\text{ab}}$

Comment: We do if $\bar{k}/l/k$, I fixed the question acordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a natural homomorphism $\text{Gal}(\bar{l}/l)^{\text{ab}}\to \text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)^{\text{ab}}$ it is not injective, the natural guess is that it corresponds to $N_{l/k}: l^\times\to k^\times$

Comment: But doesn't the fundamental theorem of infinite galois theory say that subgroups of $\text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$ correspond to subextensions $\bar{k}/l/k$? $\text{Gal}(\bar{k}/l)$ is definetly a subgroup of $\text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$, so I don't see where my mistake is?

Comment: The kernel of $G_l\to G_k^{ab}$ is $G_l\cap [G_k,G_k]$ which is larger than $[G_l,G_l]$

Comment: Concretely many abelian extensions of $l$ are not contained in $lF$ for any $F/k$ abelian.

Comment: so the problem just lies in the fact that abelianization is not left exact, right?

Comment: @curiousmathguy Also, not that you are asking, the transfer map (Verlagerung) goes the other way ($G_k^{ab}\to G_l^{ab}$): do a search in https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf for example.